# API Exception Handling (Python)

Tags: python, api, while-loop, try-catch

I request data from an API in a while/try/except loop.

The general structure is like this:

```
while (True):
      try: 
          apiloop
      except:
          print(error)
      else:
          apiloop
```

If I try it like this it continues the loop after the first exceptions, as expected.
But in the next round of exceptions, it crashes again.
So my question is how do I get to catch the exception every time and still continue with my loop. Do I need to set maybe:

```
      finally:
            continue
```

I appreciate every help.

Regards,
Angelo (Germany)

Comment: What does `apiloop` look like? You'd probably better try/except the api requests within that loop.

Comment: Please, check [ask] and provide [mre], incl. full traceback you get.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.